# Object constructor "settings" idiom

Tags: c++, constructor, idioms

I remember reading quite a while back about a constructor idiom for C++ in cases of complex object configurations.  It's particularly useful as it helps enable RAII for some nasty concepts which have *way* too many (often conflicting) options.

Here is a simple example.  Suppose you were to write a wrapper class for Win32 API windows.  To initialize a window, you need to know the window styles, the extended window styles, the initital window location, initial window size, etc.  Among the window styles, lots of options conflict and cannot be set together.  Putting all these methods in the `Window` class is prohibitive and prevents definition of proper class invariants.  Using a temporary object to group all the parameter values may help prevent impossible configurations and define a nice invariant for the `Window` class (e.g. it always holds a valid window handle).

```
class Settings
{
    ::DWORD myBasicStyles;     // takes lots of different flags.
    ::DWORD myExtentedStyles;  // even more flags.
    ::POINT myInitialLocation;
    ::SIZE myInitialSize;
    // lots more...
public:
    void setInitialPosition ( int x, int y );
    void setInitialSize ( int top, int left );
    void useSpecialBorder ();
    // lots more...
    void enableTransparency ();
    // lots more...
};

class Window
{
    ::HWND handle;
public:
    // map settings unto the horrible list of many parameters expected
    // by "CreateWindowEx()", then invoke it to allocate the resource.
    Window ( const Settings& settings );
};

// calling code.
int main ()
{
    Settings settings;
    settings.setInitialPosition(0, 0);
    settings.setInitialSize(500, 300);
    settings.setInitiallyVisible(true);
    Window window(settings);
    // ... rest of application ...
}
```

However, I cannot find the page where I read this or even the name by which it was called.  Can anyone tell me what this is called, and possibly link to a good resource on the subject?

Comment: I didn't know this had a name.

Comment: @AlexandreC. It's not a name I've seen very often.  I was just talking with a co-worker about this pattern and couldn't remember what I'd heard it called as.  I'd like to put a name on it.

Comment: Btw, how in a world are you able to call those setters on a const object anyway?

Comment: @EricZ: The Window does not call any settings, it only uses the settings.  Maybe my comment is misleading, I'll edit.

Comment: @EricZ: Added sample usage code to clarify.  Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a mix of things.

The `Settings` object is created with the [Named Parameter Idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.20).  Though usually you see it returning a reference to itself so you can chain them.

```
struct Builder {
  Builder &one(int val) { one_ = val_; return *this; }
  Builder &two(int val) { two_ = val_; return *this; }
  int one;
  int two;
};

void foo() {
  Builder builder().one(1).two(2);
}
```

`Settings` is being used *as* an [Encapsulated Context Pattern](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/246).  The link is kind of wordy.  The basic idea is that you just stick your arguments in an object and pass the object.

On a somewhat related whinge, I find offense in the idea that it encapsulates anything.  That may just be people overloading the meaning of words, though.  :)

Comment: Indeed, it's close to the builder.  I just want to avoid using the term "builder" because we're using regular constructors and the builder is not "building" anything.

Comment: Looking at these again, the link on the C++ FAQ is the one I was really looking for.  Nice find, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the name [Named Parameter Idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Named_Parameter) on teh interwebs. It is slightly different, but serves the same purpose.

Comment: This is exactly the link I was looking for.  Thanks a bunch.  It is a tad bit different from what I remembered, but it's what I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I got mixed up between the links.  This is the right name, but the description on the C++ FAQ linked to by Tom Kerr is the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather call it ***Parameter Object*** idiom if you really want a name. The name is not that important actually, compared to the idea behind it.

The idea is to group a set of related data together with an object that carries all of this data. It is worthwhile to turn these parameters into object because:

- It reduces the size of the parameter lists, and the long parameter lists are hard to understand.
- The defined accessors on the new object also make the code more consistent, which again makes it easier to understand.
- More importantly, it helps you identify those common behaviors on this set of data so that you can move into the new class. By moving these behavior into the new object, you can identify duplicated code and remove them. Furthermore, you have good encapsulation over the data. Once the implementation of any operation on the data is changed, there is only one place to change and clients are not affected.

Comment: Actually the name *is* important.  I don't need to explain it, I can just point to the [C++ FAQ item 10.20](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.20) and let people read the description.  From then on, we can just use the term "named parameter idiom" to refer to this concept.

Comment: Name is important only when most people know that name.)